# What distribution-maintained cross-compile toolchain packages exist?

Tags: embedded, cross-compilation, compiler, toolchain

I have just learned of Gentoo's [sys-devel/crossdev](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Crossdev) package. This is a package that is useful for creating a cross-compiling toolchain.

Are there any other such packages out there on other distributions?

I'm specifically interested in distro-maintained packages because I've tried a couple of others (buildroot, crosstool) and it seems that and any time the distribution touches gcc or binutils, it invariably breaks at least the building of the toolchain if not the building of the project itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Debian, there are apt-cross and dpkg-cross from [Emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/), which let you set up cross-compilation for many architectures (you get cross-compilers and libraries).

On Ubuntu, there's a [crosschain for ARM](https://launchpad.net/~hrw/+related-software), and a [project to improve on this](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/other-linaro-n-cross-compilers).

You can also create toolchain using [crosstool-ng](http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool) which is not link to a distribution.